# Replace ugly scroll-bar with vertical line characters

Tags: window, scroll-bars

Let's face it, the scroll bars for the graphical emacs are both ugly and, if you're sufficiently experienced, entirely unnecessary. Here's a picture of terminal emacs (which uses the `|` character to separate horizontally aligned buffers) adjacent to the graphical emacs on OS X (which **shudder** uses scroll bars:

[image]

My question is this: how can I get the graphical emacs to look more like the terminal emacs and eliminate the scroll bars? I don't need it to look exactly the same, but something closer than what I've got now would be rather nice.

Oh, I should also point out that simply using `(scroll-bar-mode -1)` leaves me with an empty space where the scroll bar used to be, which I don't like. I still like to be able to see where one buffer ends and the other begins.

Comment: Turn off the fringe, which is probably what that empty space is.

Comment: It might be an OSX issue? For both the GTK3 and Lucid X Window toolkits on Linux, disabling `scroll-bar-mode` leaves me with something fairly akin to the terminal: just a thin vertical line in place of the scroll bar, which is only padded by the fringes. (Emacs 24.4 & 24.5)

Comment: I've got it on both Linux and OS X with no scroll bars, and it looks like the terminal line. I turned off my fringe, but you could also change the fringe's face to match the background.

Comment: Ah...it turns out that this was a consequence of my theme. Problem solved. Thanks all!

Comment: Please post an answer and select it after the obligatory waiting period. It may help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it would turn out, my theme (the `spolsky-theme` from the `sublime-themes` package) made this vertical line disappear when the scroll bar was disabled. By changing to another theme (from the `color-theme-solarized` package), the vertical bar reappears.

Problem solved.

Answer (score 4):

Turn off scroll bars and customize option **`default-frame-alist`** to specify whatever you want for parameter`right-divider-width` (and perhaps parameter `bottom-divider-width`).

Answer (score 0):

In [`spolsky-theme.el`](https://github.com/owainlewis/emacs-color-themes/blob/4648b68e96bfde26d6e4af9f919971eef2768e5f/themes/spolsky-theme.el#L97), you can edit the line

```
`(vertical-border ((t (:foreground, *background*))))
```

to use another color than that of [`background`](https://github.com/owainlewis/emacs-color-themes/blob/4648b68e96bfde26d6e4af9f919971eef2768e5f/themes/spolsky-theme.el#L29) (which is `#161A1F`; also used for window background). Note that the fringe background also use the same color, so only changing the `vertical-border` to a constrasting color (e.g. silver, `#C0C0C0`) gives quite a clean minimal dividing line, as the fringe can not be differentiated from the background.